# Can you open Ubuntu Server from Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: boot, server

I am setting up a Raspberry Pi to run as a miniature server, and right now, I have it set up with Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.  I had first installed Ubuntu Server 20.04, then ran the commands to install Ubuntu Desktop.  Now, my computer boots straight to Ubuntu Desktop.

I'm wondering, how would I run commands to open Ubuntu Server instead?  I have a program that needs to be run from Ubuntu Server, and it won't run from the Desktop.  If possible, I'd really like to have my computer boot to Ubuntu Desktop, but then run an instance of Ubuntu Server with the Desktop still open.  If I can't do that though, I would settle for just booting directly into Ubuntu Server.

Comment: There's no server program that you cannot run in the Desktop. You can use your rpi using  GUI and at the same time run whatever server program that you want. And if you want the text-based UI , you can login in another tty . By pressing for example Ctrl+Alt+Fx to go into the ttyX ( the default range is actually 1-7 ).

Comment: Just look for an app called `terminal` in the Ubuntu Desktop. Open that and you will see the "server" in a window.

Comment: Thank you guys, that makes a lot of sense.  I actually am having trouble launching something from the terminal, and before I understood that the terminal is the server itself, I thought it was because I was launching the program from the wrong place.  I will take another look and see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"Just look for an app called terminal in the Ubuntu Desktop. Open that and you will see the "server" in a window."
– user68186 1 hour ago

"There's no server program that you cannot run in the Desktop. You can use your rpi using GUI and at the same time run whatever server program that you want. And if you want the text-based UI , you can login in another tty . By pressing for example Ctrl+Alt+Fx to go into the ttyX ( the default range is actually 1-7 )."
– Parsa Mousavi 1 hour ago

Just got these comments, and I am satisfied with them for answers.  Did not actually realize that running the terminal was actually running the server itself, and that it can still run all the same programs the even with the desktop installed.  Thank you to all who answered.